# Null Reference unity error only after the first time scripts are compiled

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a null reference error only when the first time scripts are compiled.
After that, If I make no changes in the scripts & scripts are not compiled again, I just play the game and the error is Gone.

Answer (score 0):

So this error was basically due to the order of operation errors.
This happened due to, I was calling the Public Static instance at the start and not in the awake.
I just called it in the Awake function and the issue was resolved.